# To create plist in titanium

Tags: titanium

I am developing a project in titanium and i want to create a similar functionality of plist as in iOS in titanium. Can anyone tell me that whether there is a way to do so in titanium.

Comment: What do you try to achieve by using a plist-like functionality?

Comment: @RobinEllerkmann Because already i have developed a iOS  native project and now i want to develop the same project in Titanium that is why i want to create same plist-like functionality in Titanium , is there any way to create like same?

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not done this before it should be possible due to the [Titanium documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/iOS_UI_Components_and_Conventions) (The relevant subtopic is: Settings integration).

Due to the official guide you should put your plist file in the directory platform/iphone/Settings.bundle

Comment: so may i have to create this directory structure like as you mention platform/iphone/Settings.bundle. Is It?

Comment: I would say so. I don't have this directory in my projects either but you should have a look at the KitchenSink example. It should contain the directory and a plist file.

Comment: Okay, let me check and one more point, can you please tell me any other option to get the functionality of plist .

Comment: I guess the tiapp.xml covers a lot of it. Read on here: http://bencoding.com/2012/07/15/using-titanium-ios-specific-configurations/

Comment: I am creating this project for iOS and android both and my main concern is regarding to create all the flow like as plist etc, for android specific.  So i just go through the KitchenSink example and not able to exactly getting how they use Root.plist in code. Can you please help me out on same.

Comment: You have to give Titanium platform specific information. As the bencoding link states since Titanium version 2.1 there is the <ios> tag in the tiapp.xml where you put your iOs stuff. You have another tag on the same level called <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">. There you include your Android specific stuff. This is explained in detail here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Maintaining_a_Custom_AndroidManifest.xml . For more info about the Android manifest look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: can you please tell me some way how can i read a .json extension file because i try this by below given number of line code, but getting only null value at the time of reading the file.

Comment: var fileName = 'AssignmentEntryMenuList.json';                                                            var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, fileName);                                                                               console.log("file" + file);                                                                                                            // this file we cannot locate inside directory and after this we get error var dataSrc = file.read().toString(); console.log("actual data"+dataSrc); var data = JSON.parse(dataSrc); –

Comment: Sorry I have no clue. Maybe you should ask a new question regarding this specific question?

Comment: Okay and Thanks a lot for your valuable time.

Comment: Please help on this new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845861/how-to-create-a-request-string-with-passing-different-value-in-titanium