# How to create a request string with passing different values in Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am creating a URL-String like this:

```
URLString = %@sale-ws/lots/sales?yardNumber=%@&saleFromDate=%@&range=%@&saleToDate=%@&pageSize=%@&pageNo=%@&sortBy=%@&sortType=%@&filterStartYear=%@&filterEndYear=%@&filterMake=%@&filterModel=%@&filterLocationId=%@&filterLane=%@&filterSellerId=%@&searchInSearchString=%@
```

So in Titanium i want to pass the values dynamically into a given string. 
I tried this one but did not get a proper response.

```
var urlParameterStringNew
=String.format(URLString,Alloy.Globals.SERVER_URL,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change , i have to create my URL like this

```
URLString = "%ssale-ws/lots/sales?yardNumber=%s&saleFromDate=%s&range=%s&saleToDate=%s&pageSize=%s&pageNo=%s&sortBy=%s&sortType=%s&filterStartYear=%s&filterEndYear=%s&filterMake=%s&filterModel=%s&filterLocationId=%s&filterLane=%s&filterSellerId=%s&searchInSearchString=%s",
```

Then i can simply to replace the value of %s with any other value like this

```
var finalRequestString = String.format(URLString),Alloy.Globals.SERVER_URL,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the url component and add this with your url.

```
var encoded = Ti.Network.encodeURIComponent('Pass'+' your'+' string'+' here');
var urlString = "https://www.google.co.in/search?&q="+encoded;
```

Comment: what i want while creating a request string the all %@ form URLString is replace with other value like for example-  yardNumber=%@ form URLString is replace with other value like yardNumber=2,

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own function returning the desired string value:

```
var params = [] //Add all your params to the array, order is important!

function myFunction("yourBaseString", params) { //Add all your param values
    yourString = yourBaseString;
    for (index = 0; index < params.length; ++index) {
        yourString = yourString.replace("%@", params[index]);
    }
    return yourString;
}
```

This should work because replace("@%", "paramString") only replaces the first occurrence of the string. Please give it a try and give some feedback since I wasn't able to test the function!

Comment: Robin this will work. But you can see my answer what i want and what i have to change this for desire request string.